# Listing real numbers as countable like listing rational numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals, real-numbers

like proving the set of positive rational numbers are countable, where we list the rationals as the following list, why can't we represent real numbers like the same?

If positive Rational numbers (p/q) can be listed as,

```
1/1 2/1 3/1 4/1 .. ..
1/2 2/2 3/2
1/3 2/3
1/4
..
..
```

why can't real numbers (d1d2d3.... x 10^{d'1 d'2 d'3 ...}) be listed as the following to prove they are countable

```
  ..         (-2x10^-1)(-2x10^0) (-2x10^1)
   .    ..   (-1x10^-1)(-1x10^0)    ..
  ..         ( 0x10^-1)( 0x10^0)           ...  
.... 1x10^-2   1x10^-1   1x10^0   1x10^1 1x10^2 .....
  ..             ..      2x10^0   2x10^1 ..
   .             ..      3x10^0   3x10^1 ..     ..
```

if r in R is represented as d1 d2 d3 ... x 10^ (d'1 d'2 d'3 ..)
The x axis representing the d1d2d3.. and y axis representing the powers of 10 (d'1 d'2 d'3 ..)

I can always find a number big enough and its powers of ten small enough to find a real number.

Comment: It's hard to read what you're asking, but are you trying to enumerate *finite* decimal strings? Because such a method doesn't even hit all rational numbers (like $\frac{1}3=.333\ldots$) and doesn't hit any irrational number.

Comment: another major problem is that (uncountably) many sequences of $0,1$ are not even definable (in a finite number of words / maths formulas), so you have zero chance to list them

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\pi $  so that is $3$ on one side and $.1415926.....$ on the other.  So you list it in the 3rd column and the 1415926.... row.  Which is what row exactly?

The problem is that the "powers of ten" are not integers and not enumerable as integers.  They have an infinite number of digits whereas integers always have a finite number of digits, and that makes all the difference, as Cantor famously showed.

You say you can always find powers of ten small enough.  But you find way too *many* of them. Between .2 and .3 there are an uncountable many in between.

Comment: What i meant was, to represent pi, i can goto the row with integer 314 and column (10^-2) and so on. But now i can see that to properly represent pi, we would keep going to 3141x10^(-3), 31415x10^(-4), 314159x10^(-5) ... 3...inf x 10^(-inf)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible, because reals are uncountable. One of methods of proving it is the famous Cantor diagonal argument: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument

Comment: But that doesn't address what is wrong with the op message.  It's one thing to know it won't work and even to know it can't work.  But it's another to know *how* it failed.

Comment: Rewriting Cantor's method here is unneeded and the answer is under the link.

Comment: Knowing Cantor's method doesn't explain why the op method doesn't work.  It explains that the op method CAN'T work but it leaves the op wonder where his method fails.

Comment: So where is the contradiction between the OP method and the Cantor diagonal?  That is what the op is asking.